# WPF Datagrid Expander's icon changed when scrolling down and up

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm working on a WPF app, where I have a datagrid with custom expander. The issue I'm encountering is when the user click on the + button, it changes to - and the content shows up, but when I scroll down and then scroll up, the icon changed back to + but the content stays the same. I got to know that it's because of the datagrid's virtualization. I can add `EnableRowVirtualization="False"` to the DataGrid property but it slows down the performance so much that the users would definitely notice it (as the list might contain thousands of rows). Is there a way to work around this?

Here is my code:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ProjectName.View.HomePage.OutstandingPatientDataGrid">

    <UserControl.Resources>
       // Other styles
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Border>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <DataGridCellsPresenter
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                <DataGridDetailsPresenter
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}" />
                                <DataGridRowHeader
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                                    Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">            
            <Setter Property="EnableRowVirtualization" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="EnableColumnVirtualization" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit" Value="Pixel" />
            <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Standard" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
        </Style>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="SimpleExpanderButtonTemp" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Border
                x:Name="ExpanderButtonBorder"
                >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="Transparent" />
                    <Ellipse
                        Name="Circle"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Width="34"
                        Height="20"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Stroke="Transparent" />
                    <Path
                        x:Name="Sign"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Width="10"
                        Height="10"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Data="M 0,5 H 10 M 5,0 V 10 Z"
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                        Stroke="#ADB7C9"
                        StrokeThickness="2">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="HeaderContent"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        ContentSource="Content" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <!--  Change the sign to minus when toggled  -->
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Sign" Property="Data" Value="M 0,5 H 10 Z" />
                </Trigger>

                <!--  MouseOver, Pressed behaviours  -->
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Sign" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource primary-clr}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <!--  Simple Expander Template  -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="SimpleExpanderTemp" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <DockPanel>
                <ToggleButton
                    x:Name="ExpanderButton"
                    Padding="1.5,0"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                    Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderButtonTemp}" />
                <ContentPresenter
                    x:Name="ExpanderContent"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </DockPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="ExpanderContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="outstandingPatientDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Expander
                                Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed"
                                Expanded="Expander_Expanded"
                                Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderTemp}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="410" CanUserResize="False">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                                                <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                                                <Binding Path="LastName" />
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    // ROW STYLES
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>        
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is how it looks like:
Collapsed:

[image]

Expanded:

[image]

Code Behind:

```
using ProjectName.Classes;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ProjectName.View.HomePage
{
    public partial class OutstandingPatientDataGrid : UserControl
    {
        public OutstandingPatientDataGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridRow row = TreeHelpers.FindParent<DataGridRow>(sender as Expander);
            row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void Expander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridRow row = TreeHelpers.FindParent<DataGridRow>(sender as Expander);
            row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This typically sounds like a one-way binding that should be a two-way binding, but i don't see the issue in your code, the IsChecked and IsExpanded bindings here are two-way by default. Could you share the code behind the Collapsed and Expanded event handlers?

Comment: @RobvanDaal My apologies. There is no binding in the expander element (I edited the code in the post). Also added the code behind. So essentially how it works is when the component is displayed on the screen, all the expander will be collapses. then depending on user's click on the +/- icon, it triggers the code behind and toggle the icon. But when you scroll down and then up, it's like the datagrid elements are refreshed and the icon came back to original state (+ icon) instead of - icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So regarding the solution:

You have two event handlers that set the DetailsVisibility which covers the usecase that the expander togglebutton is toggled by the user.
But the other way around is not present: when the DetailsVisibility is set (by the virtualizing system), the togglebutton.IsChecked is not set.

So instead of using eventhandlers, i would directly bind the IsExpanded to the DetailsVisibility of the row:

```
  <Expander
    IsExpanded="{Binding DetailsVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
      AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Converter={StaticResource 
      VisibilityToBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, 
      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderTemp}" />
```

The converter should be added to the resources of the UserControl:

```
<YourNamespace:VisibilityToBooleanConverter x:Key="VisibilityToBooleanConverter"/>
```

And the code of the converter would be:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class VisibilityToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;
            return visibility == Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool booleanValue = (bool)value;
            return booleanValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

But apart from that, it is strange that you use an Expander since you don't use the Header and Content of it. All you need is a ToggleButton, so i would replace the Expander by a simple ToggleButton and bind its IsChecked property like the way above.

Comment: This is brilliant Rob. It works perfectly. Thanks so much for your answer. 
I have a question though. How the ConvertBack works in this case? I have been using many custom converter but I have never used ConvertBack for any of them.

Comment: Glad it worked. For one-way bindings this ConvertBack isn't used indeed, but for input elements you typically have a two-way binding. In this case between the IsExpanded and the DetailsVisibility. So for DetailsVisibility->IsExpanded (Source->Target) the Convert is used and for IsExpanded->DetailsVisibility (Target->Source) the ConvertBack is used. For two-way bindings you typically also set the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged, otherwise the source is only updated on focus loss.